# trouble with java syntax - code does not execute

Tags: java

Why this code does not get executed?
I think the trouble is in while part, but I can't figure it out.

```
public class L {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int l = 101;
        int d = 2;
            
        if (d < l) {
            if(l % d == 0) {
                System.out.println("abc");
            } else {
                while(l % d != 0) {
                    d++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("efg");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the intended purpose of this code?

Comment: Your code seems to run well, but a logger seems missing after the `while` loop. Also, @user16320675 I just fixed the formatting

Comment: You have two print statements. Which one do you think should be executed, and why?

Comment: this is a given exercise that should do the following : If d is less than l : {
Check if l % d ==0 
If yes, show communicate, 
If no, increment d and repeat all of it
}
If not: show communicate

Comment: "increment d and repeat all of it"—The only thing repeated is `++d`. Presumably that is not what "all of it" is supposed to mean.

Comment: repeat from the beginning, so all of it

Answer (score 2):

Your code "executes" fine.

`d < l`, then `l % d != 0`, and so `d++` is ran until that is true, and the code exits without printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided executes just fine. The given values for `l` and `d` are just leading the code in the condition where you have no `System.out.println`. If you are getting any runtime errors, please post them into your question. It definitely doesn't come from the code if you get errors.